# What is an Affine Transformation?

Tags: probability, distributions

What is an affine transformation? Which families of distribution are closed under affine transformation?

Comment: Could you please be more specific in what context you need to know that, whether this is a homework question and what is wrong with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation ?

Comment: I was asked in an interview.... the question was "give an example of statistical distribution, other than normal distribution, which is closed under affine transformation".

Comment: All location-scale families are, by definition, closed under affine transformations, because in one dimension an affine transformation is just a shift in location together with a rescaling. Any family that is not already a location-scale family can be made into one by including all such transformations of its members.

Comment: To add to @whuber's excellent comment that shows that the answer to the interview questions was "any": one can make any univariate distribution into a location-scale family by replacing the density $f(x)$ with $f^*(x)=\frac{f(\frac{x-mean}{sd})}{sd}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Answer (score 5):

An affine transformation has the form $f(x) = Ax + b$ where $A$ is a matrix and $b$ is a vector (of proper dimensions, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

Affine transformation(left multiply a matrix), also called linear transformation(for more intuition please refer to this blog: [A Geometrical Understanding of Matrices](http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2018/10/24/matrices/)), is parallel preserving, and it only stretches, reflects, rotates(for example diagonal matrix or orthogonal matrix) or shears(matrix with off-diagonal elements) a vector(the same applies to many vectors/a matrix), and the "non-affine"(also a type of [projective transformation](https://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/affine-and-projective-transformations.htm) as explained in the comment by [@whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)) transformation may be like the first example in the following diagram:

[image]

More generally speaking affine transformation has the following [three properties](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/COMP770/LECTURES/2D%20Transforms.pdf#page=20):

> straight lines preserved
>   parallel lines preserved
>   ratios of lengths along lines preserved (midpoints preserved)

Comment: It is difficult to see in what sense a projective transformation is any kind of "opposite" to an affine transformation.  Indeed, affine transformations are special kinds of projective transformations.

Comment: @whuber Glad to know that, then I wonder what the other projective transformations are except affine transformation? I mean the formal name of the "non-affine" transformation? Thanks for helping me figure out the "bug".

Comment: The projective transformations are the rational functions of order 1.  On the line, for instance, they are given by four numbers $a,b,c,d$ as $$x\to \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}.$$ Usually they are limited to numbers where $ad-bc\ne 0$ for which the transformation is invertible. The transformations associated with $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(a\lambda,b\lambda,c\lambda,d\lambda)$ are the same when $\lambda\ne 0,$ making this a three-dimensional family of transformations.  The affine transformations are those for which $c=0$ and $d\ne 0.$

Comment: FWIW, what makes a transformation "affine" instead of just "linear" is that *in addition* to multiplication by a (noninvertible) matrix, one is allowed to add a constant vector to the result, thereby shifting it away from the origin.  You give only the definition of "linear transformation" here.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment the interview question you were asked was  "give an example of statistical distribution, other than normal distribution, which is closed under affine transformation".

The example to which the question refers is the fact that if you have a normally distributed random variable $X$, say $X\sim \text{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then an affine transformation is also normally distributed $aX+b \sim \text{N}(a\mu+b,a^2\sigma^2)$.

The terminology in Statistics for distributions which are 'closed under affine transformation' is $\textbf{location-scale family}$.

One example which would answer the question is the continuous uniform distribution. If $X\sim U[\alpha,\beta]$, and $Y= aX+b$ then
$$Y\sim U[a\alpha+b, a\beta+b].$$

Comment: +1.  Some care is needed with the notation when $a\lt 0,$ though.

Answer (score 0):

So I look here:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineTransformation.html

It is a rotation.  All points on a line, stay on the same line.

Per @Luca:
It can have scaling, shear, translation as well.  No bending.  Straight lines are always straight.

Comment: Affine is not just a rotation. It could be translation, shearing, scaling, rotation (and others) or any combinations of it AFAIK. I know normal distribution is closed under Affine transformations and it may be the case for the whole exponential family, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: @Luca, I was thinking rotation in the homogenous sense, where a translation was a rotation through another dimension.  Thank you for the clarification.  The center of the rotation is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then projected back to the original dimensionality of $\mathbb{R}^{m \leqslant n}$

Comment: a common type of affine transformation is $\frac{aX-b}{c}$ btw

Comment: @EngrStudent: Yeah, with homogeneous coordinates to make it a linear operation, it makes sense. But it still does not cover the full range of affine transformations, I think.

Comment: @Luca *All* affine transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be derived from the linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1}\}$ that preserve the hyperplane $x_{n+1}=1$. Few of those linear transformations will be "rotations," though: by definition, the matrix of a rotation is orthogonal.

Comment: I just thought of it in terms of physics.  I wonder if there is an augmentation that could make it literally a rotation - meeting the orthogonality criterion.

Comment: It would have to be some extraordinarily flexible "augmentation."  After all, suppose a transformation increases the length (Euclidean norm) of a vector: there does not appear to be any meaningful way to make that transformation somehow a component of an orthogonal transformation, which preserves all lengths.  Part of the issue might be that transformations which preserve lines, as you say in your second sentence, are *projective* transformations, which includes much more than rotations; yet not all projective transformations are affine.